# Is there any way I can access a bitlocker encrypted Windows 7 drive from Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, encryption, bitlocker

Is there any way I can access a bitlocker encrypted Windows 7 drive from Linux? I am not using TPM and I do have the key on a USB thumbdrive. So I have all the pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [dislocker](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/download/).

This driver uses a USB key (actually the specific .bek file on the USB drive) to decrypt a Win7 volume, so it's seem to fit your need and capacities.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. While I did manage to recover my data a while back - I think this seems to answer the question - though I have yet to test

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no Bitlocker drivers on Linux, so that is a no.

Though, you could fire up a VM and access it from there.

Comment: And after you access it, I would recommend switching to truecrypt http://www.truecrypt.org/ which works better and works in Linux also.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far, considering we know nothing of the user's work pattern. But fanboys will be fanboys.

Comment: No problem.  Keep on trucking. . .